# What is the convention for configuration files in Debian

Tags: linux, debian

The following is in regards to Debian.

From what I have read, the preferred way to provide configuration parameters to a deamon is by adding a `/etc/defaults/foo` file. I was just looking at the `monit` utility as an example, and I noticed that it uses two config files. One is `/etc/defaults/monit` which contains very little, and the second is `/etc/monit/monitrc` which is the main configuration file and contains many user-specified settings.

Why the two files instead of just one? Is this the convention or is monit doing it's own thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files inside `/etc/defaults` provide configuration values for programs started automatically and they're usually read by either upstart(8) job definitions by old SysV init scripts. Besides having some parameters to feed to some daemon when it gets started, most programs, daemons included, have their own configuration files which vary wildly in their format and their location inside `/etc/`.

In your particular example, `/etc/defaults/monit` gives information how to start the monit daemon whereas `/etc/monit/monitrc` provides detailed information in a form that possibly only monit can read.

This convention results from individual programs having different formats, though they're almost all human readable text files in a general sense, combined with a need to be able to provide some command line arguments to various daemons for their startup. The thing that is responsible doing that is usually either upstart(8) or an init(8) script both of which are unable to comprehend formats used by individual programs (ie. daemons).